# Getting action name at partial rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I need to render same partial both at index and show page, I need to have some changes on the partial based on action being called(need to hide an element at partial when it was calling from show page), I tried to use action_name method but it doesn't have the name of the action that being called, Is there any way to hide elements at partial. I tried to call current_page? helper that doesn't help

This is at show.html.erb

```
<div id="details">
  <%= render 'details', collection: @collection %>
</div>
```

this is at index page that html will be rendered on ajax success

```
<div id="details"></div>
```

Comment: What? `action_name` will contain the name of the action called unless you have done something silly like masking the variable. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

Comment: Add one or several attributes in the `locals` when rendering the template, so the template knows in which contexte it is called.